# Runtime error: Freetype library not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, freetype, glumpy

I am running Glumpy on python 3.7.2 and windows 10. I keep getting this error EVEN AFTER installing through pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\algeb\Downloads\Animoji-Animate-master\animate.py", line 3, in <module>
    from glumpy import app, gloo, gl
  File "C:\Users\algeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\glumpy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import app
  File "C:\Users\algeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\glumpy\app\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from glumpy.ext.inputhook import inputhook_manager, stdin_ready
  File "C:\Users\algeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\glumpy\ext\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import freetype
  File "C:\Users\algeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\glumpy\ext\freetype\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Freetype library not found')
RuntimeError: Freetype library not found
```

Comment: Do you have Freetype (the DLL, not the Python package) installed in your system? I don't know anything about Glumpy, but it would look a lot like it's failing to load the DLL. Note that you're apparently running 32-Bit python (!?), so you'll almost certainly need 32-Bit Freetype and you'll have to put it somewhere Python can find it…

Comment: Ok, new update, I made everything Python64 bit. But still, where do I get the freetype DLL?

Answer (score 2):

Per discussion in the comments above, the problem seems to have been that Glumpy requires the [freetype](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py) package, which requires the [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) library to be installed. You can download Windows binaries for FreeType, e.g., [here](https://github.com/ubawurinna/freetype-windows-binaries). Make sure to download the .dll for the correct platform (in your case, that would seem to be [64-Bit](https://github.com/ubawurinna/freetype-windows-binaries/tree/master/win64) now). Once downloaded, place the .dll somewhere on your machine and add the path to the directory where it's located to the `PATH` environment variable. Then the freetype package should be able to find it. More detailed installation instructions can be found in the freetype package [Readme](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py/blob/master/README.rst).

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to install the Microsoft C++ Redistributable from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/downloads/